# Why was Valak not sent back to Hell?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-conjuring-universe, the-nun

In the latest entry of The Conjuring universe, *the Nun*, the evil nun Valak was sealed back to Hell at the end of the movie with Christ's blood.

But later, it was revealed that Valak possessed the Canadian-French shortly before the final showdown.

My question is:

- If Valak possessed the Canadian-French man, what was sealed back to Hell with Christ's blood?

Answer (score 1):

No, he might have somehow tricked the protagonists into believing that he was sealed, as he had already possessed the French man before they attempted to seal him.

Another possibility is that, being a demon and having no physical body, he might have left a little part of himself in the French man, which made him maintain his connection to this world, and return easily from hell.